# PHP - JSON request not working when attempting to update product

Tags: php, json, shopify

I am using PHP to access the shopify API, I can get product data just find however when I attempt to update a product record and its variants quantity numbers it doesn't work. Oddly enough i get a json response detailing the information about the product I am trying to update and it always specifies that the inventory_quantity value and the old_inventory_quantity value are the same, so if i send a new quantity or 1 and the old quantity was 0 the response indicates that they are both 0 telling me nothing is being updated. My encoded json looks like so when dumped:

```
"{
"product":
{
"id":127417494,"variants":
{
"id":288267528,
"inventory_quantity":2
}
}
}"
```

and the response I get is :

```
" ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2013-03-18T16:47:45-07:00" ["handle"]=> string(23) "peacock-herl-small-pack" ["id"]=> int(127417488) ["product_type"]=> string(15) "Tying Materials" ["published_at"]=> string(25) "2013-03-18T16:47:00-07:00" ["published_scope"]=> string(6) "global" ["template_suffix"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(25) "Peacock Herl - Small Pack" ["updated_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-09T18:15:07-08:00" ["vendor"]=> string(19) "Pacific Fly Fishers" ["tags"]=> string(8) "Feathers" ["variants"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(22) { ["barcode"]=> NULL ["compare_at_price"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2013-03-18T16:47:45-07:00" ["fulfillment_service"]=> string(6) "manual" ["grams"]=> int(45) ["id"]=> int(288267518) ["inventory_management"]=> string(7) "shopify" ["inventory_policy"]=> string(4) "deny" ["option1"]=> string(5) "Small" ["option2"]=> NULL ["option3"]=> NULL ["position"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(4) "3.50" ["product_id"]=> int(127417488) ["requires_shipping"]=> bool(true) ["sku"]=> string(12) "762820007750" ["taxable"]=> bool(true) ["title"]=> string(5) "Small" ["updated_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-08T15:23:28-08:00" ["inventory_quantity"]=> int(5) ["old_inventory_quantity"]=> int(5) ["image_id"]=> NULL } } ["options"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> int(152687222) ["name"]=> string(5) "Title" ["position"]=> int(1) ["product_id"]=> int(127417488) } } ["images"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-08T15:23:23-08:00" ["id"]=> int(1077719361) ["position"]=> int(1) ["product_id"]=> int(127417488) ["updated_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-08T15:23:25-08:00" ["src"]=> string(93) "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0211/7110/products/peacock-herl-small-pack.jpg?v=1418081005"; ["variant_ids"]=> array(0) { } } } ["image"]=> array(7) { ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-08T15:23:23-08:00" ["id"]=> int(1077719361) ["position"]=> int(1) ["product_id"]=> int(127417488) ["updated_at"]=> string(25) "2014-12-08T15:23:25-08:00" ["src"]=> string(93) "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0211/7110/products/peacock-herl-small-pack.jpg?v=1418081005"; ["variant_ids"]=> array(0) { } } } } array(1) { ["product"]=> array(16) { ["body_html"]=> string(169) "

Beautiful peacock sword that is often used for tails on patterns like Zug Bugs and Spruce Fly streamers. Also used in many atlantic salmon and steelhead patterns.
```

I have checked the id's over and over and it appears to be hitting the right endpoint but for whatever reason it will not accept a new quantity value, I don't know if i am missing a required parameter or what but im pretty much at a dead end with this.

In case anyone is curious my cUrl request looks like this

```
if ($data != null) {
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(        
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'PUT', //sets method if specified
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //Causes curl_exec() to return the response
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false, //Suppress headers from returning in curl_exec()
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => array($this, 'header_callback'), //call header_callback upon receiving headers
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data)),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,        
    ));

  $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
  // close curl
  curl_close($ch);
  // return json data
  return json_decode($this->response, true);
}
```

Comment: On quick glance the variant id 288267528 is not the variant id that is in your return string. Maybe if you used the correct variant number it would work? Also shouldn't there be brackets around the variants array in your Json?

Comment: you have to update the variant into product, but not the product, check the manual http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update inventory alone then the payload array should look like this

```
$inventory = array (            
    "variant"=>array (
        "id"=>{{'your_variant_id'}},
        "inventory_quantity"=>{{'your_inventory_quantity'}}
    )               
);
```

Your URL should look like this

```
$url = "variants/".{{'your_variant_id'}}.".json";
```

Call the above url with `PUT` method along with `$inventory` array as parameter.

I have a working demo, which is using the above method to manage inventory.

You can see that demo at http://sarkutils.in/swpanel with `demo:password`